# Is there a smarter way of using the code located in another namespace

Tags: opengl, clojure, jogl

i have this on my core page. which creates the window but doesn't draw anything

```
(deftype Program []
   GLEventListener
     (display [this drawable] (in-ns 'game-c.drawtriangle))
     (init [this drawable] "init")
     (dispose [this drawable] "dispose")
     (reshape [this drawable x y width height] "reshape")
   )

;set up and start window methods/functions
 (def glp (GLProfile/getDefault))
 (def caps (GLCapabilities. glp))
 (def window (GLWindow/create caps))

 (def ani (FPSAnimator. window 60 true))

 (doto window
  (.addGLEventListener (Program.))
  (.setSize 600 600)
  (.setTitle "CloGame")
  (.setVisible true)
  (.start ani)
 )
```

this is the part for drawing the triangle on the window. but it doesn't do that. i just start the repl and it shows me it blank window, a function return value and an error message(detailed below)

```
(ns game-c.drawtriangle)

(def gl (.getGL4 (.getGL window)))
(def tri [ [0.0 0.0] [0.5 0.0] [0.5 0.5] ])
(doto gl
  (.glCreateVertexArrays 1 tri)
)
```

this is the repl output

```
#object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x49db0a8e "game-c.core"]

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught IllegalStateException: Can't 
change/establish root binding of: *ns* with set on thread nREPL-worker-
1-Display-.x11_:0-1-EDT-1, compiling:(game-c/core.clj:33:2)
```

im thinking there might be another way of using the code located in drawtriangle but i am not sure how you would do that

Comment: and yes i've looked at other questions similar but they seem to specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(ns game-c.core
  (:require [game-c.drawtriangle :as tri] ))
...
 (display [this drawable] (tri/drawtriangle))
...
```

and

```
(ns game-c.drawtriangle
  (:require [game-c.core :as core] ))
(def gl (.getGL4 (.getGL core/window)))
...
```

Comment: that sorta worked but now the (def gl...) can't locate the "window" var